# Creating a third network on a single router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ssid

This might be a silly question but I'm having difficulty finding a reliable answer...

Example situation: I tend to use only my router's 5 GHz band. But I would also like to share wifi with the next door neighbours during an internet outage with their ISP. My router's guest network is already dedicated to another group, so here's my question:

If my unused 2.4 GHz band gets an SSID and password which are distinct from the SSID/password of the 5 GHz network, will these separate credentials result in two networks that are isolated from/separately encrypted from one another? (Three in total, counting the guest network).

I realize there are more sophisticated ways to securely divide bandwidth and isolate traffic, but if the above idea could work then it would allow me to share internet with said neighbours but require almost no setup and configuration in the moment, other than say, coming up with a new password for them. Thanks in advance for your advice and help!

Comment: The credentials are not what determine whether the networks of the two SSIDs will be isolated from each other.

Comment: What model is your router?

Answer (score 0):

This depends heavily on the particular router implementation, i.e. does its interface support the required configuration.

In principle, it is possible to do a complete isolation of internal networks. The only coupling that'll be left is the share of the bandwidth and performance of the router itself, but that is inevitable.

I've did exactly this isolation on OpenWRT-flashed TP-Link N600 (TL-WDR3600) router (and this could be achieved in the same way on any OpenWRT-flashed router). The isolation was supported by creating the dedicated firewall zone and disabling forwarding of any traffic between my LAN zone and that additional zone.

Answer (score 0):

In most if not all consumer grade wifi access points, you have 2 vlans. The main network and the guest network. Both 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz share the same network as the LAN ports on the router, and only the guest network is shielded off.

In your case it is a better idea to give them the guest network password, given that it is setup correctly anyway or use additional hardware. If you really need it separate, either get a router that supports adding vlan's or get another router.